# How to add a calendar event which has multiple timezones?

Tags: macos, calendar

Can I manually add a flight to calendar, writing its start time in one timezone and its end time in another timezone?

Comment: Events like this are usually handled by location data.  If you create an event that starts at 9:00am on EST and lasts for 3 hours (12:00pm EST), if you travel to CST for example, it will be 11:00am there and show your event has concluded at the correct time.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Calendar does not currently support multiple time zones for a single event and there are currently no workarounds to address this. Each calendar even has a single time zone.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/change-the-time-zone-mmfbbb458d/icloud):

> By default, your calendars and their events use the time zone set in
> Settings on iCloud.com. You can create events and view calendars in
> other time zones by turning on time zone support in Calendar on
> iCloud.com.

Also from [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/use-different-time-zones-icl1035/mac):

> By default, calendar events are displayed in your computer’s current
> time zone (set in Date & Time settings). However, you can change the
> time zone and set individual events to use a different time zone.